# Django Fails with Basic Auth with Ngnix + Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to load balance 2 gunicorn servers with nginx. I am required to have basic auth on the application, so I thought I would stick the auth on the nginx server.

However for some reason my Django completely fails when I enable basic auth the nginx server. Everything works perfectly after disabling basic in my nginx conf.

Here is my nginx conf.

```
upstream backend {
    server 10.0.4.3;
    server 10.0.4.4;
}




server {
    listen 80;


    location / {
         proxy_pass http://backend;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
             auth_basic "Restricted";
           auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_set_header REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

    }

    location /orders
    {
     auth_basic "off" ;
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error importing module keystone_auth.backend: "No module named keystone_auth.backend"
```

I thought it might be some headers that I need to pass through. Is there another way to get basic auth on Django bearing in mind that it needs to be load balanced. Or is my ngnix config missing some stuff?

Comment: (#include obligatory basic auth over 80 is frowned upon for production at least).  How are you doing auth on the django side?  It would seem to me to just require using the remote_user middleware, so I'm not sure where the keystore_auth.backend is coming into play

Answer (score 0):

The keystone_auth.backend had mistakenly be included from another settings file, I was still unable to get BasicAuth working, but eventually solved the issue by writing my own Auth Back end as described here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/